# remove last comma in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

using `XSLT 1.0`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:variable name="xxxx" select="@name" />
    <xsl:if test="../../../../fieldMap/field[@name=$xxxx]">...
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">////this is not work correctly as last() number is actual last value of for loop and position() is based on if condition.
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

can you suggest me how can i remove last '`,`' here ?

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output data? I don't think it's possible that "position() is based on if condition"; or maybe I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`position()` and `last()` should be based on the loop, and not the `xsl:if`. What I think you are saying is that you are actually wanting to check if this is the last element for which the `xsl:if` is true, as such an element may not actually be the last element in the loop.

I would suggest combining your `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:if` into one, and selecting only those elements for which the condition is true. That way you should then be able to check the position in the way you were expecting

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[@name = ../../../../fieldMap/field/@name]">

    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: here , i have fieldMap/field/@name are multiple field/@name elements and also other comparing element are multiple elements */@name . Will it work like - all match of */@name with ../../../fieldMap/field/@name in for condition ?

Comment: Well, why don't you try it and found out! ;) Alternatively, could you edit your question with this information, and ideally show your input XML, and expected output, as this would make it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: sorry for bit late responding. Yes, it works for me and it compares with all set of elements. its example also, in other post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095746/in-xslt-many-to-many-attributes-comparing-in-for-each-condition.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your inner `if` to:

```
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[
                   @name = ../../../../fieldMap/field/@name])">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

BTW this works because of "general comparisons". I.e.

```
A = B
```

is true if any node selected by A is equal to (has same value as) any node selected by B.

For the sake of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would probably put `../../../../fieldMap/field/@name` into a variable and declare it before the `for-each` loop begins:

```
<xsl:variable name="fieldNames" select="../../../../fieldMap/field/@name" />
<xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:if test="$fieldNames = @name">...
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*[@name = $fieldNames])">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Again, $fieldNames can be a nodeset of multiple attribute nodes, and when we say `$fieldNames = @name`, we are asking whether the value of `@name` equals the value of any node in `$fieldNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Translate, replace, split-join won't work in XSLT.I implemented a simple way which is working fine in my XSLT

Sample code:

```
  <xsl:variable name="ErrorCPN">
    <xsl:if test="count(/DATA_DS/G_1)>0 and count(/DATA_DS/CPN)>0">
      <xsl:for-each select="$BIPReportCPN/ns3:BIPCPN/ns3:BIPEachCPNDelimitedValue">
        <xsl:variable name="BIPEachCPNDelimitedValue" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="count(/DATA_DS/G_1[CPN=$BIPEachCPNDelimitedValue]/CPN)=0">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($BIPEachCPNDelimitedValue,',')"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($ErrorCPN,1,string-length($ErrorCPN)-1)"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I created one variable and inside if and for each conditions implemented, for every loop required value is concatenated with a comma, at the end of the loop one extra comma will be there which is not required to us. So, we can take the substring and eliminate last comma.

Otherwise use the sample code and try.